# Opengl ES Analysis removed in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I can't find the tool `Opengl ES Analysis` in instruments after upgrade to Xcode 9. Has it been removed or replaced? How to get it back or is there any alternatives?

Comment: I tried launching Xcode **8**'s Instruments, and it isn't there either...

Comment: Same here; can't find it.  Are we supposed to entirely rely on capture frame?